# browser limit in horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I am making a website where my client wants all of his portfolio to be in one horizontal line. It's about 40-50 images and goes up to 30.000 pixels wide.

When the page loads not all the images are shown. If I reload the browser the images are shown correctly. Is there such a limit in horizontal scrolling?

I tried putting a width through css but nothing happens.

Comment: Some sample code please.

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers, or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your stylesheet

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```