# Horizontal scroll limit in web browser?

Tags: web-applications, browser

This is somewhat like [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883658/browser-limit-in-horizontal-scroll). 
I have a webpage with huge width. Is there a limit on width of web page?